# React Native - i want to hide green message on header in the first screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

who help me hide green message on header in the first screen  :( 
Thanks 
[image]

Comment: That only appears in dev mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide it. You only can hide red and yellow boxes from warnings and errors. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#warnings
Anyway, that only appear in develop mode, don't be afraid to see it in production.
Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

To disable the yellow box place `console.disableYellowBox = true;` anywhere in your application. Typically in the root file so it will apply to both iOS and Android.

For get more details please check [official document](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#yellowbox-redbox)

Answer (score 0):

To hide the green loading message on launch of the app do the following In your project XCODE.
1) Select Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Select Run from the menu on the left and change the build configuration to release.

2) build the app and run .